# MySQL: Synchronize a DB without using trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to, monitor specific tables of database A, whenever any changes happens to the tables of A, I need to know what the changes are, say the value of a column in a row was changed from 1 to 2, and then do some changes in another database B. The limitation is nothing except query can be done on database A. So no trigger can be put on A. The idea might be to keep a replication of A and put triggers on the copy of A? Not sure if this is possible. Any suggestion on how this can be done?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This will be **highly** specific on what concrete database you're using. Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Using MySQL. Thank you.

Comment: how big is the table on A?

Comment: table A is about 10 columns and less than 10K records.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use replication what you do after replication depends a lot on the details of you use case.

For example if you replicate from serverA.tableA -> serverB.tableA and then copy from serverB.tableA to serverB.tableAprime.  After the copy the following query will give you a list of any subsequent changes

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM tableAprime
```

This might be simpler and more useful then using a trigger.

Or you could use a trigger on serverB.tableA and not make serverB.tableAprime.